# Django 1.2: Custom form field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a dynamic form that contains either one or several MultipleChoiceFields or ChoiceFields. I want to display an instruction to the user, e.g. for ChoiceField: "Select one of the following", and for MultipleChoiceField: "Select any of the following"

How can I do this? I tried subclassing each of these fields, but I couldn't get the value back out in the template.

Thanks

EDIT

I tried something like:

```
class MultiWithInstruction(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, instruction=None, **kwargs):
        self.instruction=instruction
        return super(MultiWithInstruction, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I couldn't retrieve the value of 'instruction' in the template.

Comment: Please also show us how you add the field to the form and how you tried to retrieve the value of `instruction` in your template!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`help_text`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text)?

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(help_text='Pick one of these', ....)
```

And then in the template you could do something like this:

```
<p>{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}</p>
{% if field.help_text %}<p class="help_text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label value in your form field:

```
myfield = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Select any of the following')
```

Comment: i'm already using that too. i need to add an extra field that's like a label or help text

Comment: Form instances are just like any Python object. You can set an attribute to be anything you like. For example, say you create your form as form = MyForm(), you can then just set form.additional_label = 'This is my text'. In your template, you can call {{ form.additional_label }} and output the value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't find an easy way (without overriding a lot of stuff from django.forms) so I came up with this quick-and-dirty solution.

Define a new template filter, that splits a string into a list, given a separator; see [this simple snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/211/) by Ciantic. Save the snippet as `templatetags/whatever_name.py`.

In `forms.py`, fill the `help_text` attribute of the field with your help and instruction strings, separated by '#' (you can choose whatever separator you want, of course); something like

```
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(help_text = '%s#%s' % (help_string, instruction_string), ...)
```

`help_text` is a string (already marked safe), so you can't put a list in it (this is why the custom split filter is needed).

And this is an example of a template that shows help and instruction strings for each field in the form:

```
{% load whatever_name %}

{% for field in form %}
    help: {% filter split:"#"|first %}{{ field.help_text }}{% endfilter %}
    instruction: {% filter split:"#"|last %}{{ field.help_text }}{% endfilter %}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, you can't use `as_p`, `as_table` and `as_ul` to render the form.